Compilation Issue with TeXmaker on Windows 10 - "File not found" Error with MiKTeX
I'm having an issue with TeXmaker on Windows 10. Here’s what I’ve done:
I installed MiKTeX from this link: https://miktex.org/download
Then, I installed TeXmaker from this link: https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html
However, when I try to compile a LaTeX document, I get an error message in a dialog box saying "File not found."
Do you have any idea what might be causing this issue? Any suggestions for resolving this error would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I’ve checked that MiKTeX is properly installed and paths are configured.
TeXmaker is set up to use MiKTeX as the distribution.
